# NSMutableString becomes (null) when converted from NSData with length 4000+

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I'm sending XML request to some server and getting some response data from it using NSURLConnection:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection  
{  
    NSMutableString *receivedString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:_receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];       
    NSLog(@"Size of DATA: %d",[_receivedData length]);  
    NSLog(@"Body: %@", receivedString);  
}
```

When length of my data is about 4000 - I can normally see the received data in output. But when length of data becomes greater (6000, 10000, etc.), Output shows that my receivedString becomes null!

How can I still save my data to the string, when it's length becomes greater? Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you change NSMutableString to NSString?

Comment: Maybe related to this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485190/nsstring-initwithdata-returns-null

Comment: Does it print the length as 10000 and then print the string as null? Does `(receivedString == nil)` evaluate to YES? What happens if you log `[receivedString substringToIndex:500];`? Does that also show up as null or actual text?

Comment: @JamesPaolantonio, unfortunately the same.

Comment: @SVD, no, I tried all types of encoding...

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist, this is result for `[receivedString substringToIndex:500];`  

Size of DATA: 6169      
Body: (null)    

and this gives YES: `(receivedString == nil)`

Comment: maybe consider a streaming XML parser?

Comment: can we get your XML file somewhere?

Comment: It's important to understand that NULL is returned from many Objective-C functions when they encounter an error.  You should always test for NULL (nil) after you get the string back in this case, since there's always the possibility of an error from the other side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your data is encoded with `NSUTF8StringEncoding`?  Double check the data being returned to you.  `initWithData:encoding:` will return `nil` if the data is not properly represented by the encoding.

An easy way to test this is to use the same data object, and create a string with incremental pieces of the same data until it fails, then look at the byte that causes it to fail.

I'd bet a piece of southern fried catfish that you have an improperly (or mismatched) encoded byte in that data.

Comment: Yes! For example, if I send a request that give response with NSData of short length - it gives XML to the Output:

`<RESPONSE_GENERAL><RETURN_STATUS><ID>65538</ID><DESCRIPTION>Status unknown 65538, Add it to StatusStringConvertor.cpp.</DESCRIPTION><YOUR_TOKEN1>-1</YOUR_TOKEN1><YOUR_TOKEN2>-1</YOUR_TOKEN2><MESSAGE_ID>-1</MESSAGE_ID></RETURN_STATUS><ACTION_TYPE>get_request</ACTION_TYPE></RESPONSE_GENERAL>`

Comment: That is not the same thing.  You need to actually look at the long data item to determine the bad byte.  I guarantee it's not the length by itself.  You can create strings much larger than 10000.

Comment: You're right!

I checked with tracer. Looks like server compresses response with zip if size of response becomes larger than 4k. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you have your answer.  BTW, those are my two favorite words -- especially on the rare occasions they come from any of my children.