# iOS objective-C NSData to NSString return nil, how to ignore the invalid UTF-8

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, nsdata

`data` is downloaded from website,

```
NSString * html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

`html` is `nil`, but

```
NSString * html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

will have the content. 
Since the website contains Chinese characters, if using Ascii, the Chinese cannot be displayed. I guess there are some invalid UTF-8 in the website, so that make the first code not working.

Is there any methods can keep using UTF-8 but ignore some invalid error?

Comment: It's likely that your data was not downloaded in UTF-8 format.

Comment: I open the website (http://lib.cityu.edu.hk/search~S8/?searchtype=X&searcharg=你好&searchscope=8&SORT=D&extended=0&SUBMIT=Search ) and check the encoding in safari, it is UTF-8, with Chinese character displayed normally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found a solution.

[Vincent Guerci's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4985534/2361752)

add libiconv to your project and let it clean the invalid UTF-8, after cleaning, the NSData is safe to pass to `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Details implementation is:

1. Add "libiconv.2.dylib" in "Link Binary With Libraries" to your target.
2. `#include "iconv.h"`
3. Add this function:

Objective C:

```
- (NSData *)cleanUTF8:(NSData *)data {
    // this function is from
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485190/nsstring-initwithdata-returns-null
    //
    //
    iconv_t cd = iconv_open("UTF-8", "UTF-8"); // convert to UTF-8 from UTF-8
    int one = 1;
    iconvctl(cd, ICONV_SET_DISCARD_ILSEQ, &one); // discard invalid characters
    size_t inbytesleft, outbytesleft;
    inbytesleft = outbytesleft = data.length;
    char *inbuf  = (char *)data.bytes;
    char *outbuf = malloc(sizeof(char) * data.length);
    char *outptr = outbuf;
    if (iconv(cd, &inbuf, &inbytesleft, &outptr, &outbytesleft)
        == (size_t)-1) {
        NSLog(@"this should not happen, seriously");
        return nil;
    }
    NSData *result = [NSData dataWithBytes:outbuf length:data.length - outbytesleft];
    iconv_close(cd);
    free(outbuf);
    return result;
}
```