# NSString's - initWithData:encoding:

Tags: ios

According to Apple this [method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithData:encoding:):

"Returns nil if the initialization fails for some reason (for example if data does not represent valid data for encoding)."

I used this snippet to do some testing.  Sometimes, with certain decodedData, I got the decodedString is null and other times, it is blank.

Question: Given any invalid data, when will that method return either a blank or null?

```
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if (decodedString)
{
    NSLog(@"Normal string: %@", decodedString);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"decodedstring is null: %@", decodedString);
}
```

Edit:  decodedData is not nil.

Comment: I see only one reason it may return a blank string, the `decodedData` is blank or empty. But there are many reasons to fail and get `nil`. Mostly as it's said in documentation it's because of encoding. Your data may be non UTF-8, having no Content-Type header and encoded in a way it's not possible to determine. Please take a look into this answer and thread itself, there are some reasons discussed. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3486325/3317354

Comment: @teamnorge: decodedData has value and is not nil.  I know it contained invalid data.  But I need to find out when the method return blank or nil.

Comment: @user523234 what do u mean by blank NSString with length 0 or nil pointer.

Comment: @vigneshkumar: string with length is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try to figure out it the following.

```
   if (decodedData)
{
    NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if(decodedString){
        NSLog(@"Normal string: %@", decodedString);
    }else{
        //NSUTF8StringEncoding invalid/not supported encoding.Try it with another encoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"decodedData is null: %@", decodedData);
}
```

note: returns nil when not supported NSUTF8StringEncoding

Comment: I did not state explicitly in my question but the decodedData is not nil.